# wxpython DataViewIndexListModel Text Wrap

Tags: dataview, wxpython

Is it possible to wrap the text in the cells of the wxpython dataviewctrl?  I have some long strings which are making the grid cells very large.

Comment: Add more information to your question. Do you have any code? What's the problem and how does it differ from the expected behavior?

Comment: The program is intended to extract the data from a database table, there are 48 tables out of the 107 tables in the database that use this form.  The problem is is that some of the data strings are more like small paragraphs, but the output is shown in the wxpython dataview grid as a single line that does not wrap.  The code is about 500 lines and I am not sure how to snip the required section so that it will run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I was able to get the cells to wrap by using textwrap in a function called from GetValueByRow().  It seems to work; but, does gives a somewhat strange string of text when editing the cell.